# MASM Commands - Problems on DOSBox

Tags: windows, dos, masm, dosbox

I am new on this forum and wanted some assistance on MASM programming. Currently I am learning MASM from my course instructor and he has told us to use MASM 6.15 (works easily for other Windows versions but not for Windows 7 & 8) for compiling our programs. I use Windows 8, so I was not able to compile those programs. So I came across a site that said to use a DOSBox emulator to use MASM on Windows 8! I have installed it and have done all the required tasks to make it work properly but I am still not able to compile my MASM program on DOSBox! When I try to compile, it gives the error that this program cannot be run in DOS made. Any assistance would be really appreciated!

I got MASM from this link:
http://www2.hawaii.edu/~pager/312/masm%20615%20downloading.htm

...and another site from which I got its commands is:
http://ansmachine.blogspot.com/2013/12/masm-using-dos-box-in-windows-8.html#.U3c8JvmSy27

Comment: I haven't used MASM in ages (the functionality has been rolled into the Visual Studio toolset, where it is far more convenient), but if I remember correctly, even version 6.15 could assemble 32-bit applications. Why doesn't it work on Windows 7/8? Do you get an error when you tried to use it? What does it say? (The apps don't work in DosBox because they're not DOS applications--they are Windows apps!)

Comment: Well when i try to compile it does not recongnise its commands, and gives the message "illegal command"

Comment: The question is too broad, the answer would be a beginner's book. Please show the source of your masm program and the command line you used to "compile" (better: assemble) it.

Comment: I have also studied some where that through visual studio, masm can be implemented but i'm not been able to understand how to do it!!

Comment: @rkhb i used the commands: for compile or as u said assembling it,i used command "masm prog.asm" but it gave the error that this program cannot run in DOS mode.

Comment: I'd like to show you the steps to assemble it with **your** source and assembler (where did you "masm" get from?). So please edit your post accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, so the problem is that you are writing 16-bit code, which won't run on 64-bit versions of Windows. And it won't run in DosBox because MASM assembles Windows applications, not DOS applications. I don't know what book you're using to learn from, but it is obsolete.

Comment: @Cody Gray so what should i do,should i use visual studio instead of this..

Answer (score 2):

`DOSBox` is appropriate to run 16 bit DOS programs, not 32/64 bit Windows programs. MASM can produce Windows programs since version 6.x. So you don't need DOSBox if you don't **explicitly** want to make DOS programs.

Your example is a 16 bit DOS program ("INT 21h"). To build it you have to open a "Windows Command Prompt" aka console, **not** DOSBox. If you don't know how, search at Google. I assume the path to your assembler is `c:\masm615\bin`. Now type:

`c:\masm615\bin\ml.exe prog.asm`

Note that I used `ml.exe` instead of `masm.exe`.

Now you can run `prog.exe` in `DOSBox`.

Search in the net for 32 bit MASM programs which you can assemble in the same way, but run in the current Windows console. Then you can and should forget anything with `INT 21h`!

---

And now let us do it with Visual Studio (VS). I'll show it with VS 2010 Express, but other versions of VS should be similar.

You need a Windows program (.MODEL FLAT), let's call it **prog.asm**:

```
.686p
.MODEL FLAT

includelib msvcrt.lib
extern _printf:PROC
extern _exit:PROC

.DATA
    format1 db "%s",10,0
    string1 db "Hello world!",0
    format2 db "The square root of %f is %f.",10,0
    double1 REAL8 10.0
    double2 REAL8 ?

.CODE
_main PROC

    push OFFSET string1
    push OFFSET format1
    call _printf

    fld double1
    fsqrt
    fstp double2

    push DWORD PTR double2 + 4
    push DWORD PTR double2
    push DWORD PTR double1 + 4
    push DWORD PTR double1
    push OFFSET format2
    call _printf

    push 0
    call _exit

_main ENDP

END _main
```

Open a console. First you need to know the location of `vcvarsall.bat`. Type in:

`dir /s /b \vcvarsall.bat`

After a few minutes you should get something like `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat`. Type in this line in double quotes and press ENTER. Everything is okay when you see: Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 x86 tools.

Now you can assemble and run prog.asm:

```
ml prog.asm
prog.exe
```

Comment: Ok so i followed your steps and its working!! now i just want to know that i should now use 32 bit masm programs instead of 16 bit right???

Comment: @user3647239: Take a look at my edit. There is much more to know: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/afzk3475.aspx

Comment: :dir /s /b \vcvarsall.bat this gave me an error message can u please  explain it more to me...!!does /s and /b refers to disks!!

Comment: No one can help you without the full error message. You can also use the search function of your Explorer, in this case you must collect the full path by yourself. I've got no Windows 8, just XP. I've tested my suggestions. If the problems are caused by issues of Win8, I can't help.